# Диаграмма с накоплением через VBA в EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, диаграммы

Для своей работы пишу некоторый макрос в Excel'е через VBA. Понадобилось сделать диаграмму с накоплением. Включив макрорекордер и вставив диаграмму на лист вручную получил следующий код:

```
Range("Таблица1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(286, xl3DColumnStacked100).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Лист1!$I$2:$J$3")
```

Ничего сложного в коде нет. На первой строчке мы выделяем мою умную таблицу, во второй строчке создаём объект Chart и выделяем его, а в третьей строчке мы задаём диапазон исходных данных для нашей 3д диаграммы с накоплением. В результате получаем диаграмму которая представлена в файле Пример.jpg
[image: диаграмма, которая создавалась вручную.]

Но если повторить этот код просто нажав F5 мы получим совершенно другую диаграмму!
[image: диаграмма, которая получается с помощью кода]

Меня этот результат не устраивает, необходима именно диаграмма с накоплением! Прошу помощи сообщества разобраться в проблеме!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `, PlotBy:=xlRows` к аргументам для `SetSourceData`

```
Range("Таблица1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(286, xl3DColumnStacked100).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Лист1!$I$2:$J$3"), PlotBy:=xlRows
```

Код, создаваемый макрорекордером, бывает очень полезен, прежде всего как справочник. Но макрорекордер имеет множество недостатков, в т.ч. ряд действий он не фиксирует. Например, настройку источника данных для диаграмм - по строкам или по столбцам. См. скрин ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При построении диаграммы макрорекордер применяет значение по умолчанию для необязательного параметра `PlotBy` метода [`Chart.SetSourceData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata) и строит эту диаграмму по столбцам, не записывая дальнейшую его настройку. Поэтому для построения "по строкам" нужно указать второй параметр `PlotBy` явным образом - `xlRows`.

Кроме того, код макрорекордера обычно избыточен и не вполне удобен.
Поэтому предлагаю переписать код таким образом, явным образом указав лист и таблицу:

```
Sub test1()
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        .Shapes.AddChart2(286, xl3DColumnStacked100).chart.SetSourceData Source:=.ListObjects("Таблица1").DataBodyRange, PlotBy:=xlRows
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло. Буду ждать пояснений :)